Is there a way to perform windows authentication from prod IIS Server without Authorization(Sign-in)
In my .net6 web API project, the requirement is to perform a Windows identity authentication.
I have chosen the Authentication dropdown as "Windows" while creating the project. For testing purposes, I just built only one endpoint and it returns 4 simple parameters as a response.
my program.cs file
using IdentityTestWindows;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();


builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

My controller
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.DirectoryServices.Protocols;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;

// For more information on enabling Web API for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860

namespace IdentityTestWindows.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;

        public LoginController(IConfiguration config)
        {
            this._config = config;
        }

        // GET: api/<LoginController>
        [HttpGet("authenticateLogin")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Authenticate()
        {
            try
            {              
                var result = new
                {
                    ApplicationCodeExecutedUsing = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name.ToString(),
                    IsUserAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated.ToString(),
                    AuthenticationType = User.Identity.AuthenticationType.ToString(),
                    UserName = User.Identity.Name,
                };               
                return Ok(result);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }    
}

This code works as expected in the local IIS Server app. But my requirement is this should work fine in a common network. Let's say all my user's machines follow the pattern Organization_Domain\{Employee_ID} as their Windows identity. Authorization should not be asked for users who place requests with the above matching criteria.
I have explored Windows Identity Authentication and in .NET Framework I came across the  tag in web.config also for intranet scenarios "impersonation" is more suitable. But .NET6 web.config is not accepting the tag authorization in the web.config.
So, I am requesting help on this issue.

The question contains a lot of conflicting statements, non-existent terms (what is a "common network"?) and unneeded code, like the LoginController. Windows Authentication is performed between the browser and the IIS server, the application is never involved. As long as the browser and the web server are on domain machines, using domain accounts, nothing more is needed. If you don't deploy to IIS, you can configure ASP.NET Core's built-in server (Kestrel) to use Windows authentication. No controller is needed. The web app account though should be a domain account

Did you check the docs? Configure Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core shows both options (IIS or Kestrel)

Whether the browser displays a login dialog is entirely up to the browser's settings and policies. If the browser is configured to automatically log into intranet or trusted servers, no popup will be displayed

In IIS you can set up authentication through the IIS manager tool.

Your web.config setting with impersonation is not working with .NET latest version because it is designed to be cross platform. you can use Negotiate authentication handler to achieve your requirement. for that you can follow below steps:

Set up IIS to enable windows authentication and disable anonymous

Enable "Integrated Windows Authentication" in Internet Explorer setting.
Select "Local Intranet" and select the "Custom Level" or "Advanced" button.
Scroll down to "User Authentication" > "Logon".
Check the box next to "Enable logon in intranet zone only".

Set up the custom authorization policy to check if the user matches the organization's domain pattern:
public class EmployeeIdRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    // Custom requirement 
}

public class EmployeeIdAuthorizationHandler : AuthorizationHandler<EmployeeIdRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, EmployeeIdRequirement requirement)
    {
        var windowsIdentity = context.User.Identity as WindowsIdentity;
        if (windowsIdentity != null && windowsIdentity.Name.StartsWith("Organization_Domain\\"))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}



Then register this handler and apply the policy to your controllers or actions as needed:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, EmployeeIdAuthorizationHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("EmployeeIdPolicy", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new EmployeeIdRequirement()));
});

[Authorize(Policy = "EmployeeIdPolicy")]
public class YourController : ControllerBase
{
    // Controller actions 
}


When I type "whoami" in cmd, my machine shows "DomainName\Employee_ID". If I type the same on my server it shows "ServerName\userNameInServer". My application when put on prod IIS, shows the same server name as Windows identity. So, does it mean they are not on the same network(intranet) or am I mistaken?

If I type "echo %USERDOMAIN%" on both the user machine and Server, the result is different. I am asking this because, after performing the above steps also, I still see the SignIn prompt being triggered by the server.

@KarumanchiSrikanth your observation regarding the different username seems because how authentication is being handled in development vs production. Could you please make sure both the machine you are trying is in domain joined network. under which app pool identity your application is running on iis?could you try adding the site to the "Local intranet" zone in Internet Explorer.
